# Stimulus reflex stopped working in production rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulus-reflex

I have a blog and use stimulus_reflex to approve/unapprove comments on posts.  I also use it to publish/unpublish posts.  It works fine on the localhost and was working on the production server but it is no longer working.  The only thing I did was install an ssl certificate with certbot.  It stopped working so I remove certbot from the server completely but it still did not work.  I have reinstalled the ssl certificate.

Here is the code for the post edit page for the publish and unpublish buttons:

```
<% if @post.published? %>
  <a href="#"
    class='btn btn-secondary btn-block'
    data-reflex='click->PublisherReflex#unpublish'
    data-post-id='<%= @post.id %>'>
    Unpublish
  </a>
<% else %>
  <a href="#"
    class='btn btn-dark btn-block'
    data-reflex='click->PublisherReflex#publish'
    data-post-id='<%= @post.id %>'>
    Publish
  </a>
<% end %>
```

Here is the publish_reflex.rb fild:

```
class PublisherReflex < ApplicationReflex
  def publish 
    post = Post.find(element.dataset[:post_id])
    post.update(published: true, published_at: Time.now)
  end

  def unpublish 
    post = Post.find(element.dataset[:post_id])
    post.update(published: false, published_at: nil)
  end
end
```

On post I found on here I tried creating a initializers/warder_cookies.rb file:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user, auth, opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = user.id
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = 30.minutes.from_now
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |_user, auth, opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = nil
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = nil
end
```

And the post said to add the following code but didn't give a file so I searched and added it to the channels/connection.rb file:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      # rubocop:disable Lint/AssignmentInCondition
      if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I view the nginx server log I get this:

```
2021/03/28 16:11:34 [error] 1365851#1365851: *131507 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 2601:282:1880:3a10:e5b0:e2df:dbe6:9c58, server: allaboutjudo.com, request: "GET /cable HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.D7yaVlf/agents.s/core:", host: "allaboutjudo.com"
2021/03/28 16:11:40 [error] 1365851#1365851: *131515 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 98.38.139.55, server: allaboutjudo.com, request: "GET /cable HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.D7yaVlf/agents.s/core:", host: "allaboutjudo.com"
```

On the localhost when I open the console I see:

```
ActionCable is connected
```

But on the production site if I click the unpublish button I get this error:

```
Error invoking action "click->stimulus-reflex#__perform"

 The ActionCable connection is not open! `this.isActionCableConnectionOpen()` must return true before calling `this.stimulate()`
```

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial I learned about stimulus_reflex it never mentioned that the redis server had to be running.  I saw in a quickstart guide to stimulus reflex that it must be installed and running so I logged into the server and ran the command

```
$ redis-server
```

and now the the reflexes work!